# Unable to open a filehandle in a Proc::Daemon::Init'd script in perl

Tags: perl, daemon, filehandle

I have a perl script which i am running in daemon mode with the following code.

```
Proc::Daemon::Init()

# Anonymous subroutine.
my $sub = sub {

   # Call to the function which opens the filehandle
   my $content = RandomPackage::GetContent({ $args});
}

# Forking 
Proc::ForkAndForget->({JOB => $sub });
```

The RandomPackage::GetContent has the following definition.

```
use File::Temp;
sub GetContent {
   my ($args) = @_;
   my ($filehandle, $filename) = File::Temp::tempfile();

   open $filehandle, ">", $filename or "cant open the filehandle";
   <Some operations>
   return ;
 }
```

While running the script in daemon mode, I get the error cant open the filehandle.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error did `open` return? Replace `or "cant open the filehandle"` with `or die("Can't open the \"$filename\": $!\n");`

Comment: That's not how File::Temp should be used. `$filehandle` already contains an open handle to `$filename`.

Comment: Keep in mind that Proc::Daemon::Init tries to closes every file handle your process owns except those you tell it not to close.

Comment: "cant open the filehandle"

Comment: Nope, that's not an error returned by `open`. Perhaps you should read my comment again: What error did `open` return? To find out, replace `or "cant open the filehandle"` with `or die("Can't open the \"$filename\": $!\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is a permission error.

Print the contents of $! it will inform you of the type of error.